# How come slicing returns a lists but indexing returns a value

Tags: python

**Indexing ---> returns string**

```
Input:
l1 = ['bbq', 'rr']
[l1[0] + l1[0], l1[1]+l1[1]]

Output: ['bbqbbq', 'rrrr']
```

**Slicing  ---> returns lists**

```
Input: [l1[:1] + l1[:1], l1[1:2]+l1[1:2]]<br>
Output: [['bbq', 'bbq'], ['rr', 'rr']]
```

Comment: Just to confuse things, if `l1 = 'a string'`, then `l[0] == l[:1]`!

Comment: Indeed, Indexing ---> returns string, Slicing ---> **still** returns a string. If yoe are slicing a string, that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about this:
When you are slicing something, why are you slicing? You want a range of values. How else would Python return the group of values except within a container? Therefore Python assumes anytime you are slicing, it needs to require multiple values, therefore it wraps it in a container for you. Likewise, when you are indexing, you are telling Python you want exactly one object from inside the container, not the container itself.

Pretend you are getting your laundry from the laundry mat. If you are picking up more than one blanket, you bring your hamper. If you are only picking up one blanket, you can carry it by hand. If you brought your hamper one day and there was only one blanket, you would still but it in your hamper even though there was only one.

Comment: It's silly that he asked just to answer, but it IS a good answer for the question he asked.

Comment: It's not silly (*this has been done by a lot of high reputation users*), but personally I don't think it's a good question.

Comment: I was working with a particular problem for a long time. I came to stackoverflow for help but as I was typing out the problem the came to me in a 'ah hah!' like moment. I was not going to posts this publically but then I read  "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged." in the FAQ

Comment: Not really sure why my question is getting downvoted. This site is designed for people of all skill levels, even though that question/answer may seem obvious to you there are people who it may be of assistance to. This is why it's difficult for newbies join this community; people talk about in meta how to make this community more friendly but when it comes down to it most people are unwilling, such as circumstances like this.